# How to check amount of gpu memory usage in docker

Tags: docker, gpu

I'm trying to check how much of GPU memory consume my docker container.
Unfortunately docker stats do not show this stat.
Another thing is that container is running on arm64 architecture (NVIDIA Jetson AGX XAVIER) and there is no command `nvidia-smi`.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There is an package for Jeston (NANO, Xavier, TX1...) jtop
To install on Jetson if pip is not intalled
`sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Upgrade pip
`python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Install jetson-stats
`sudo -H pip3 install -U jetson-stats`

Reboot the system
`sudo reboot`

After reboot run in termial
`jtop`

There are several tabs in 4 one can check gpu memory usage.